# Style checkbox as switch with Bootstrap-classes in a Rails App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I'm trying to use bootstrap classes in my rails project to style a checkbox as a [switch](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#switches) but I don't know why it doesn't work. It's probably a syntax error (although I've tried many combinations) Has anyone encountered this problem before?

```
<div class="checkbox form-check form-switch">
     <%= sched.check_box :closed, {checked: sched.object.persisted?}, false, true, class: 'form-check-input', id: 'flexSwitchCheckDefault' %>  <%= sched.label :closed, day[:label], class: 'form-check-label', for: 'flexSwitchCheckDefault' %>
</div>
```

If it helps, the app is currently on [Heroku](https://health-care-opening-hours.herokuapp.com/companies/new)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Bootstrap is not properly installed or integrate into your application

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">Checked switch checkbox input</label>
</div>
```

This is code for test put inside HTML page is this code convert in switch means bootstrap integrated successfully

link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/

Comment: The problem I’ve is regarding the syntax for the .erb file, I suppose.

Comment: `<div class="checkbox form-check form-switch">
<%= sched.check_box :closed, {checked: sched.object.persisted?}, false, true, class: 'form-check-input' %>  <%= sched.label :closed, class: 'form-check-label' %>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap v4 (as tagged) then you have the wrong class names.

Try this:

```
<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
     <%= sched.check_box :closed, {checked: sched.object.persisted?}, false, true, class: 'custom-control-input', id: 'flexSwitchCheckDefault' %>  
     <%= sched.label :closed, day[:label], class: 'custom-control-label', for: 'flexSwitchCheckDefault' %>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#switches

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="custom-control custom-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customSwitch1">
  <label class="custom-control-label" for="customSwitch1">v4 switch element</label>
</div>

<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckChecked">v5 switch element</label>
</div>
```